# Windows phone 8 : MessageBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have developed xaml application for WP8.I am using MessageBox to show alert messages.It was working fine, but now it is not working in Lumia 920, same works fine on Lumia 620.Whiletesting on Lumia 920 multiple alerts came once then i just pressed ok button continuously. Was it a problem?After that messagebox alerts not working.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just Restart your device and check it.

Comment: thanks a lot.that was a simple issue.